# How much sealing wax is a unit of sealing wax?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting, pricing

It says you can buy it for 5 sp but doesn't list a weight. All it does is give a description" "When you press a signet ring into warm sealing wax, you leave an identifying mark." So how would I buy a gallon of this stuff if I don't even know how much 5 sp will get me?

Comment: Where is that description of sealing wax/signet ring from? (I can't find it)

Comment: @Someone_Evil [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/sealing-wax) gives that description. I'm not sure if/where any printed materials do.

Comment: @mdrichey: I don't see it anywhere in the PHB. I've asked on the DDB Discord what the source of that description (and that of the [signet ring](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/signet-ring)) is.

Comment: What do you need it for? Do you definitely need sealing wax, or would buying candles be sufficient?

Comment: @V2Blast There are many other pieces of mundane equipment that have short descriptions in DDB that don't appear to come from any of the books.

Answer (score 6):

The [Wikipedia article on sealing wax](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealing_wax) is a good overview of what sealing wax is and how it’s used.

For our purposes, I just want to draw your attention to the unit described. Basically, when you bought real-world sealing wax you got a stick of wax about the length of a pen and about as thick as a person’s thumb, or the equivalent quantity of loose granules of wax. This is very approximate, and obviously exact measurements would vary by the seller, but this is the general scale of a real-world unit of sealing wax.

Since D&D approaches world details by  taking our understanding of the real world as a base onto which we can add fantastic elements, we can just assume that D&D-fantasy sealing wax is sold in the same approximate units that were convenient for real-world people.

A stick of wax about the length of a pen and the thickness of a thumb is, let’s approximate, about 5 inches by 1 inch square, which is a volume about 5 cubic inches or, rounded up to be generous, about 3 oz of solidified wax. Let’s assume the wax doesn’t expand appreciably when it melts just so we can get a ballpark number. That means a [US gallon (defined as 231 cubic inches)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallon) can contain about 46 sticks of our estimated sealing wax unit.

So a gallon of sealing wax would run you about 230 pieces of silver, or 23 gp.

Again, this is *very* approximate, since “sticks” of sealing wax isn’t an exact volume to begin with, or even standardised between different colours or qualities of wax, or from seller to seller. **Somewhere in neighbourhood of 20–30 gp is about the idea.** Ask your DM to pick a more exact price when your PC goes to buy the stack of sticks from a merchant, so you can move on to melting gallons of sealing wax onto things.

Comment: One might even be able to talk with a local Alchemist about making you a bulk special order.

Comment: @Alk More likely a chandler or stationer.

Comment: Yes I miss remembered the Alchemical Crafting from Xans it lists acid,alchemist’s fire, antitoxin, oil, perfume, and soap. Though it would not be a stretch to believe an alchemist makes the wax.